# Retrieve the value of Boolean variable through Java Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to get the value of a boolean variable through reflection but I end up getting an `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
Test c = new Test();
Class clazz = c.getClass(); 
java.lang.reflect.Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField("flag");
field.setAccessible(true);
Object val = field.get(clazz);
```

Where this is the `Test` class:

```
public class Test {
    private boolean flag;
}
```

I end up getting error stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set boolean field com.Test.flag to java.lang.Class
```

Could someone please explain where it is going wrong.

Comment: Can you show your `Test` class?

Answer (score 4):

you should get this field from OBJECT, not CLASS...

```
Object val = field.get(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `field.get(clazz)` to `field.get(c)`.